# Не получаеться нарисовать колесо

Tags: c++, opengl

Хочу такие колёса нарисовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А получается вот так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код :

```
bool My_circular_koleso(double x, double y, double R, double R1)
{
    if(R1 >= R){
        printf("R1 more big that R (this exeption) \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    GLfloat vertires_chikl[2196]; int d =0;
    bool datchik = true; GLfloat t = 0; GLfloat t_n = 0.0528;; // x = datcik, t = Angle param, t_n = new Angle param.
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 122; i++)
    {
        if(datchik== true)
        {
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R1*cos(t))); d++;  // по оси x first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(y+(R1*sin(t))); d++;  // по оси y first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka

            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka

            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka

            datchik = false;
        }
        else
        {
             vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R1*cos(t))); d++;  // по оси x first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(y+(R1*sin(t))); d++;  // по оси y first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka
            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka
            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka

            datchik = true;
        }
        t = t_n;    t_n = t_n + 0.0528; // сдвигаем угол
    }

    // позиция
    GLuint indices_chikl[2196];
    for (int i =0; i <= 2196; i++)
        indices_chikl[i] = i;

    // цвет
    GLfloat cwet_chikl[2196];
    Rainbow_color(false, cwet_chikl, 2196);

    // единая переменная для обхода позиций
    GLuint iboHandle;
    // создаём единую переменную для хранения дескриптора
    GLuint vaoHandle;
    // Создаём и заполняем буферные обьекты
    GLuint vboHandles[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, vboHandles);
    GLuint positionBufferHandle = vboHandles[0];
    GLuint colorBufferHandle = vboHandles[1];

    // ----
    // заполнить буфер координат
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertires_chikl), vertires_chikl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // заполнить буфер цветов
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cwet_chikl), cwet_chikl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // ----
    // Создать обьект массива вершин
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

    // Активировать массивы вершинных атрибутов
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Координаты вершины
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Цвет вершины

    // Закрепить индекс 0 за буфером с координатами
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // Закрепить индекс 1 за буфером с цветом
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // ----
    // Создём и закрепляем обходной(позиционный) буфер
    glGenBuffers(1, &iboHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices_chikl), indices_chikl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // ----

    ShaderProgram shaderprogram;
    shaderprogram.loadShaders("basic.vert", "basic.frag");
    shaderprogram.use();

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 244, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Принцип прост

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так ((((

Comment: Что-то у вас вершин совсем маловато генерится и нету смежных.

Comment: а может это cull face? хотя не похоже..

Comment: и вероятно Вам надо использовать TRIANGLE_STRIP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот смотрите - чтобы создать сегмент кольца, приближаемый трапецией, нужно два треугольника

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для первого вершины определяются радиусами и углами

```
R_Inner, t1
R_Outer, t1
R_Outer, t2

R_Outer, t2
R_Inner, t2
R_Inner, t1
```

У Вас, похоже, углы сдвигаются после каждого треугольника, а нужно после двух

Answer (score 0):

Во общем вот правильный кусок кода, я ещё случайно одну точку неверно задал в цикле задания точек. В общем вот вся функция с исправленными ошибками.

```
bool My_circular_koleso(double x, double y, double R, double R1)
{
    if(R1 >= R){
        printf("R1 more big that R (this exeption) \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    GLfloat vertires_chikl[4392]; int d =0; // было 2196
    bool datchik = true; GLfloat t = 0; GLfloat t_n = 0.03; // x = datcik, t = Angle param, t_n = new Angle param.
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 488; i++)   // было 244
    {
        if(datchik == true)
        {
            printf("datchik == true \n");
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R1*cos(t))); d++;  // по оси x first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(y+(R1*sin(t))); d++;  // по оси y first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka
            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka
            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka

            datchik = false;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("datchik == false \n");
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R1*cos(t))); d++;  // по оси x first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(y+(R1*sin(t))); d++;  // по оси y first tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka
            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*cos(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R*sin(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x two tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka
            //---
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R1*cos(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(x+(R1*sin(t_n))); d++;   // po osi x tre tochka
            vertires_chikl[d] = GLfloat(0.0); d++;            // по оси z first tochka

            datchik = true;
        }
        if(datchik == true){ printf("Angle news param \n");
        t = t_n; /* t_n = t_n + 0.0528; */ t_n = t_n + 0.03; } // сдвигаем угол
    }

    // позиция
    GLuint indices_chikl[4392];
    for (int i =0; i <= 4392; i++)
        indices_chikl[i] = i;

    // цвет
    GLfloat cwet_chikl[4392];
    Rainbow_color(false, cwet_chikl, 4392);

    // единая переменная для обхода позиций
    GLuint iboHandle;
    // создаём единую переменную для хранения дескриптора
    GLuint vaoHandle;
    // Создаём и заполняем буферные обьекты
    GLuint vboHandles[2];
    glGenBuffers(2, vboHandles);
    GLuint positionBufferHandle = vboHandles[0];
    GLuint colorBufferHandle = vboHandles[1];

    // ----
    // заполнить буфер координат
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertires_chikl), vertires_chikl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // заполнить буфер цветов
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cwet_chikl), cwet_chikl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // ----
    // Создать обьект массива вершин
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoHandle);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);

    // Активировать массивы вершинных атрибутов
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Координаты вершины
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1); // Цвет вершины

    // Закрепить индекс 0 за буфером с координатами
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // Закрепить индекс 1 за буфером с цветом
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferHandle);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    // ----
    // Создём и закрепляем обходной(позиционный) буфер
    glGenBuffers(1, &iboHandle);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboHandle);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices_chikl), indices_chikl, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // ----

    ShaderProgram shaderprogram;
    shaderprogram.loadShaders("basic.vert", "basic.frag");
    shaderprogram.use();

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 1464, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0); // 732
//    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 1464, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[image: Мммм да , картинка не очень лициприятна , но это уже задел на новый вопрос :3]